# MKMapView select and deselect custom MKAnnotationView IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

Im using a Custom MKAnnotationView

```
- (void)plotAnnotationsOnMap
{
    for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in locationPickerView.mapView.annotations) {
        [locationPickerView.mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < [allEstabelecimentos count]; i++)
    {
        Pin * pinMap = [allEstabelecimentos objectAtIndex:i];
        [locationPickerView.mapView pinMap];
    }
 }
```

And when the user taps inside it, i show a custom view :

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
//    NSInteger indexOfTheObject = [self.mapView.annotations indexOfObject:view.annotation];

    if([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[Pin class]])
    {
        CalloutView *calloutView = [[CalloutView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 230, 100)];
        [calloutView setDelegate:self];
        CGRect calloutViewFrame = calloutView.frame;
        calloutViewFrame.origin = CGPointMake(-calloutViewFrame.size.width/2 + 15, -calloutViewFrame.size.height);
        calloutView.frame = calloutViewFrame;

        [calloutView setEstabelecimento:(Estabelecimento*)[view annotation]];

        [view addSubview:calloutView];

        _showCustomCallout = YES;
    }
}
```

The problem is when the user deselects the pin, if he taps inside the map, and outside the pin, it should just dismiss the pin, but if he taps inside the custom view, it should call another view:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    NSInteger indexOfTheObject = [self.locationPickerView.mapView.annotations indexOfObject:view.annotation];

    if([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[Pin class]])
    {
        if(_showCustomCallout)
        {
           Estabelecimento * temp = [self.locationPickerView.mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:indexOfTheObject];
            HomeSalaoViewController * viewController = [[HomeSalaoViewController alloc]init];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
            viewController.currentEsta = temp;
            _showCustomCallout = NO;
        }

        for (UIView *subview in view.subviews ){
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _showCustomCallout = NO;
    }
}
```

Whenver its shows the pin its calling the other view.

Comment: Yeah because you put your transition code in `didDeselectAnnotationView:` so anytime a pin is deselected you'll push the next view.

Comment: Wait, what do you mean "Whenver its shows the pin its calling the other view"?

Comment: Anyway... Try adding a tap gesture recognizer to your `CalloutView` and add the transition to the method linked to it.

Comment: already tried that, the UITapGestureRecognizer dont work, even with setUserInteractionEnabled = YES

Comment: I couldn't tell you why that is without seeing that code... But a `UITapGestureRecognizer` can definitely work.